# Editing string when meet '|'

Tags: c#, string, algorithm

I have a question that may be a little stupid but I can't figure it out.

I read from .xml and that's not a problem but I have a string that looks something like this:

```
string str = "3|+5|*4/2+8*32|+7";
```

and I have to change it from this state to -

```
(3+5)*4/2+8*(32+7).
```

Basically when there is "|" before any of +,-,/,* I have to remove "|" and add ( ) and after that I have to calculate the sum witch is not a problem again. 
I try splitting the string or going through all his chars but nothing works like I want.

**I just need some direction where to start from. If you have any idea write so I can try it.**

When there is `3|+5` the method should see the | and add open bracket before the first number like this `(3+5` and after that it has to check is the operation after the number 5 contains `|` and if not it has to put close bracket after 5, otherwise proceeds to next number and when find a operation without `|` it has to put close bracket before the operation.

Comment: Can you paste the code you use for calculating the sum? It might be easier to modify this to cater for the additional operators.

Comment: You'd probably have to create a rather large and complex string manipulation function to handle all the possible combinations you could find, i.e. to handle this : `"3|+5|*4|+5|*4|+3" = "(((((3+5)*4)+5)*4)+3)"`

Comment: Should that be (3+5)(4/2+8)(32+7)? What should be the answer? 3120?

Comment: This seems like an ambiguous grammar to me. For instance, what is the expected output of `1|+2|*3|+4|`? Should it be `(1+2)*(3+4)` or `(1+(2*3)+4)`?

Comment: Shouldn't the result be : `((((3)+5)*4/2+8*32)+7)`. Else it is hard for me to understand the logic priority...

Comment: I think all `|x` operators have the same priority, so we take them from left to right.

Comment: When you have `3|+5` it has to be `(3+5)` when you have `3||+5` then you will have `((3+5))` but then that is not a valid string. When one bracket is opened there wont be any other open brackets until the first is closed so you cannot have `(1+(2*3) + 4)` and `1|+2|*3|+4|` is not a valid string (the last | at the end of the string). Sorry I forgot to say that.

Answer (score 1):

Precondition for this solution is that input expression will never have parentheses. If input does have them then this is not the solution, and some other solution is needed.

Break up your input string into list of tokens:

```
string expression = "3|+5|*4/2+8*32|+7";
List<string> tokens = TokenizeExpression(expression); // You code this
```

Contents should be `{ "3", "|+", "5", "|*", "4", "/", "2", "+", "8", "*", "32", "|+", "7" }`. Now for each `"|op"` operator make a new list where elements `"exp1", "|op", "exp2"` are replaced with single string `"(exp1 op exp2)"`. Go from beginning to the end, or in other words form left to right. Iterations should go like this:

```
{ "(3+5)", "|*", "4", "/", "2", "+", "8", "*", "32", "|+", "7" }
{ "((3+5)*4)", "/", "2", "+", "8", "*", "32", "|+", "7" }
{ "((3+5)*4)", "/", "2", "+", "8", "*", "(32+7)" }
```

Repeat until all `"|op"` operators are replaced.

The result is concatenation of all elements in the list, which is this: `"((3+5)*4)/2+8*(32+7)"`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that works with your input. But i'm afraid there are many ways this could fail. Maybe it gives you   an idea anyway:

```
string str = "3|+5|*4/2+8*32|+7";
char[] operators = {'+', '-', '/', '*'};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int index = str.IndexOf('|');
if (index > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        Char c = str[i];
        if (c != '|')
        {
            sb.Append(c);
            continue;
        }
        Char nextChar = str[i + 1];
        if (operators.Contains(nextChar))
        { 
            // next char is operator, find index before last number
            int countLeft = 1;
            while (i - ++countLeft > 0 && Char.IsDigit(str[i - countLeft]))
                ;
            int countRight = 2; // skip operator
            while (i + ++countRight < str.Length && Char.IsDigit(str[i + countRight]))
                ;
            countLeft--;
            countRight--;
            int start = i - countLeft;
            string numLeft = str.Substring(start, countLeft);
            string numRight = str.Substring(i + 2, countRight - 1);
            sb.Remove(start, countLeft);
            string expr = string.Format("({0}{1}{2})", numLeft, nextChar, numRight);
            sb.Append(expr);
            i = i + countRight + 1;
        }
    }
}
else
    sb.Append(str);
```

The calculation part is very easy with the `DataTable.Compute`-trick:

```
DataTable calculator = new DataTable();
object value = calculator.Compute(sb.ToString(), null);
double result = System.Convert.ToDouble(value); // 328.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that will help a lot. I know the trick with the `DataTable.Compute`.